# Mixing WinJS and XAML

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, winjs

We have a WinJS app that is not performing as well as it would if it were written in XAML/C#. Is it possible to move the app into XAML, piece by piece, by either hosting XAML inside the WinJS or hosting WinJS in XAML? Or is a complete re-write necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite. Hosting XAML inside a WinJS app is impossible, and hosting WinJS inside a XAML web view would be extremely difficult - the communcation across the two technology stacks would be difficult enough that you wouldn't save anything time or effort wise.

Comment: Technically, hosting WinJS inside of a WebView is trivial (it's just like hosting it in the browser).

Answer (score -1):

The better question is: Why is your app not performing as expected?

In general, a WinJS app should perform the same as (or in some cases, better than) a C#/XAML app. What isn't performing well for you? Rendering? Layout? Non-UI code? (which you could move to a C# or C++ WinRT component, if it's perf sensitive in a way that JS execution or memory management is holding you back - but these cases are rare).

So what performance analysis have you conducted that has led you to believe the problem is actually WinJS? (or the HTML/JS runtime?)

Comment: This is an old question but in the context of when I wrote this, we were using a javascript charting library. On an x86 it took about 30ms to render on the ARM Surface it was 300ms. We had about 10 of these charts in one view. You can see where this is going. Also, I'm hesitant to give any weight to your assertion that WinJS should perform as good or better than C#/XAML. Please link to evidence as this does not match anything I've read.

Comment: The rendering stack for WWAs is just faster (and lighter weight) than that of XAML, though the latter is getting better and may catch up in Win10. The HTML/CSS runtime makes better use of DComp and DManip, is faster at layout, element creation, and has less marshalling overhead. WinJS's ListView control was measurably faster than XAML's in Win8, though they were closer in 8.1.

Main point is: Saying "rendering charts with this third-party library is too slow in our usage, so lets rewrite our app in a different technology" makes absolutely zero sense.

Comment: Oh, and the Surface RT was just crazy slow. But the fastest performing apps on it (like Tweetium, for example) were HTML/JS/C++, not XAML/C#.

Comment: When we did a PoC using some third party chart controls in XAML/C# vs HTML on the Surface, it was like night and day. It made a lot of sense to us and our stakeholders when we ran them side by side.